# EntityQuery restrictions in JBoss Seam

Tags: jboss, seam

Is it possible to create restriction clauses for the Seam EntityQuery, that are ORed instead of always being ANDed together?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at setRestrictionLogicOperator(operator). Operator can be "and" or "or". This will "and" or "or" all restriction statements.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware you can also write everything in the `private static final String EJBQL` ,EL is interpreted here too, so you can combine OR and AND like this :

```
select c from Cat c where c.gender=#{cat.gender} and ( c.name=#{cat.name} or c.color=#{cat.color} )
```

You can even avoid problems with null values like this  : `where c.name=#{empty cat.name ? "defaultName" : cat.name }`

Comment: However, this will not get you the benefit of only considering those restrictions that do not depend on empty values.